# Focus on Date from TextField in JqueryUI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm wondering if there is anyway that I can make jQueryUI's Datepicker auto focus on the month specified from text input box. For instance say in the text box I put 07/04/2015 it would auto focus on July 2015. Right now I have it being populated from a text field but it loads on the current month automatically.

Comment: Have you tried `$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", $(".textbox").val() );`?

Comment: I did try something similar...I tried yours though and it worked! Thank YOU!

Comment: If you want post that as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", $(".textbox").val() );
```